# Android set setReverseLayout for RecyclerView LayoutManager

Tags: android

i added layoutmanager to recyclerview on xml code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/messagesView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>
```

now i can't set `setReverseLayout` by this code:

```
messagesView.getLayoutManager().setReverseLayout(true);
```

in this case i don't like to set `Layoutmanager` via java code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `app:reverseLayout="true"`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView android:id="@+id/transcript"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
  app:reverseLayout="true"
  app:stackFromEnd="true" />
```

(from [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.6/RecyclerView/Transcript) from [this book](https://commonsware.com/Android))